# SQL Query to get results on a 24 hour graph

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following structure to store clicks from a website on a Mysql database:

```
select * from contenido_clicks;
+-------------+-------------+------------+
| idContenido | fecha_click | servicetag |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
|           5 |  1392829606 | HJCS302    |
|           8 |  1392832379 | HJCS302    |
|           5 |  1392832433 | HJCS302    |
|           5 |  1392832435 | HJCS302    |
|           5 |  1392832437 | HJCS302    |
And so on...
```

Here I have lots on entries from different days and hours, and I need to get all of them and place on a 24 hours graph, to show the hours in the day that people makes more clicks. I can get the clicks per hour with:

```
SELECT cc.fecha_click div 3600 as Horas, COUNT(cc.idContenido) as Clicks 
FROM contenido_clicks cc 
GROUP BY fecha_click div 3600 ASC
```

But I dont know how to merge them in a 24 hour table.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to make grouping by date/hour?

Comment: Where is hours field in your database table ?

Comment: Not exactly. If several devices makes click on different days between 11:00 and 12:00, I need the total clicks on that hours.

Comment: @SohailYasmin : I only have the timestamp on fecha_click

Comment: Is `fetcha_click` an unix timestamp? You should use `DateTime` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Horas domain table with 24 rows and left join your contenido_clicks table with it

```
create table Horas
(
  Hora integer not null
)

Insert into Horas (Hora) vlaues (0)
Insert into Horas (Hora) vlaues (1)
.
.
.
Insert into Horas (Hora) vlaues (23)

select *
from Horas h
left join (
   SELECT cc.fecha_click div 3600 as Horas, COUNT(cc.idContenido) as Clicks 
   FROM contenido_clicks cc 
   GROUP BY fecha_click div 3600
) as hh on hh.Hora = h.Hora
order by h.Hora
```

Comment: I see that I need a Hora field to resolve this. I thought that whith the timestamp should be enought.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do some thing like this

```
  SELECT * 
   FROM contenido_clicks
  WHERE DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) > fecha_click
```

I think this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the solution provided by jean, I write the following query:

```
SELECT h.hora, COUNT(cc.idContenido) as Clicks 
FROM horas h 
LEFT JOIN contenido_clicks cc ON h.hora = DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(cc.fecha_click), '%H') 
GROUP BY h.hora;
```

And get the following result:

```
+------+--------+
| hora | Clicks |
+------+--------+
|    0 |      0 |
|    1 |      0 |
|    2 |      0 |
|    3 |      0 |
|    4 |      0 |
|    5 |      0 |
|    6 |      0 |
|    7 |      0 |
|    8 |      0 |
|    9 |      5 |
|   10 |      3 |
|   11 |      7 |
|   12 |      4 |
|   13 |      3 |
|   14 |      0 |
|   15 |      5 |
|   16 |      1 |
|   17 |      5 |
|   18 |      8 |
|   19 |      0 |
|   20 |      0 |
|   21 |      1 |
|   22 |      0 |
|   23 |      0 |
+------+--------+
24 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which are the correct results.